# Assigning a fixed local IP address to a particular MAC address in Linksys wireless routers

Tags: router

I'm hoping to assign a specific local IP (ie 192.168.1.102) to a particular MAC address whenever this device connects with the Linksys wireless router. I've read that it's [not recommended to turn off DHCP](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/41067-42-setting-static-addresses).

How can I accomplish this otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Most routers provide a way for you to assign a particular IP address to a particular MAC. You're actually telling the router's DHCP server to just always make this particular assignment, so you don't need to turn off DHCP -- other devices you didn't specify a static assignment for will just get assigned some other address the router has available.

Also, this means that you should still configure your device to obtain an IP address via DHCP, rather than setting a static IP address.

Comment: can you generally describe to make the IP assignment in a linksys router?

Comment: What model is it?

Comment: the classic linksys WRT54G

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that model supports static IP assignment via DHCP with the stock firmware. That router does, however, support many 3rd party firmwares like DD-WRT and Tomato that do have that feature. If you're not interested in flashing another firmware, you can see http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/WRT54G-Static-IP-Question/td-p/152001 for some alternative approaches.

Comment: I've setup IP addresses, gateways, and DNS on a specific computer according to the suggestion in the link you provided. The link didn't say where to change those settings, but i assumed it's in Wireless Network Connection Properties --> Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4) Properties. After configuring a static IP address, the computer can surf the web for a while. But overtime, the computer doesn't have any connectivity anymore (no access to Internet, cannot connect to 192.168.1.1. It's not the router's fault because other computers using this router to surf the internet have no problem).

Comment: To fix the problem I must run "Diagnose" which fixes the problem after "reset the wireless adapter". But I don't want to run Diagnose every other hour, or losing connectivity during a file transfer. Do you know what's not configured correctly?